# php preg_replace question

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have this code:

```
$text = '[iframe=200x200]http://stackoverflow.com[iframe] ';
$text = preg_replace(
    '/\[iframe=(.*?)x(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/iframe\]/ms', 
    '<iframe style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); width: \1px; height: \2px;" src="\3"></iframe>', 
    $text
);
echo $text;
```

Why is it not working?

Comment: moustafa, it's not an issue any more, but next time consider posting what *"not working"* actually means. For clarity, you could post the actual output and the output you had expected it to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$text = preg_replace('/\[iframe=(.*?)x(.*?)\](.*?)\[iframe\]/ms',
        '<iframe style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); width: \1px; height: \2px;" src="\3"></iframe>',
        $text);
```

There were some unwanted slashes in `\[\/iframe\]` which needed to be changed to `\[iframe\]`

**EDIT:**

Actually your input string looks incorrect, as it does not have a closing iframe tag:

```
$text = '[iframe=200x200]http://stackoverflow.com[iframe] ';
```

should be

```
$text = '[iframe=200x200]http://stackoverflow.com[/iframe] ';
```

In cases where your string contains `/` you can make use of some other delimiter to make avoid escaping `/` found in the string. Something like:

```
$text = preg_replace('#\[iframe=(.*?)x(.*?)\](.*?)\[/iframe\]#ms',
            '<iframe style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); width: \1px; height: \2px;" src="\3"></iframe>',
            $text);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your input string has an error. The `/` at the closing tag is missing

[iframe=200x200]http://stackoverflow.com[/iframe]